# El botón no ejecuta el metodo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo un método que ejecuta un escaner, el problema es que al pulsar el botón, no se ejecuta dicho método, llevo varios días intentando dar con la solución y no se que puede ser. Dejo la parte del método con el OncreateView.

Quiero añadir que el botón me deja de funcionar cuando implemento en el RecyclerView que al darle click (en el recyclerview) se habrá el elemento seleccionado y pueda borrarlo (esto se habré en otro fragment).

¿Que puede ser?

Gracias.

```
public class EscanerFragment extends Fragment {

EditText etCodigo;
Button btnLeerCodigo;


public EscanerFragment() {

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escaner, container, false);

    etCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.etCodigo);
    btnLeerCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_escanear);

    escanear();


    return vista;
}

public void escanear(){
    btnLeerCodigo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator intent = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(EscanerFragment.this);
            intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
            intent.setCameraId(0);
            intent.setBeepEnabled(false);
            intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            intent.initiateScan();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Buenas, en primer lugar deberías indicar que estas utilizando una libreria, en este caso Zxing para escanear codigos de barras.

¿Al hacer click en el botón te lanza algún error? 

El código parece correcto. prueba a mostrar un toast u otra cosa.

Comment: Buscando en google `ItemIntegrator`, verás que hay entradas, unas cuantas, de gente que tiene el mismo problema que tú y es que parece ser que en Fragments se comporta distinto a si lo lanzas en una Activity.

Comment: @PabloR. Buenas, no, no me aparece ningún error, simplemente no funciona, mañana probare a mostrar un Toast, a ver si así el botón reacciona. Muchas gracias, mañana os digo en cuanto pueda.

Comment: @SuperG280 estoy intentando buscar soluciones buscando a través de eso, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya he conseguido que funcione, gracias a todos.

Se ve que en fragments da problemas como bien decía @SuperG280, así es que lo he hecho en una activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_codigo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_codigo = findViewById(R.id.etCodigo);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_escanear);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            escanear();
        }
    });
}

public void escanear() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Escanea el codigo de barras");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() != null) {
            et_codigo.setText(result.getContents());
        } else {
            et_codigo.setText("Error al escanear");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

En tu código no tienes implementado un `RecyclerView`, si estas teniendo problemas al implementar el clic, seguramente es porque se esta perdiendo la referencia del botón al cual le asignas el listener.

Un ejemplo de como asignar un listener a un elemento dentro de un `RecyclerView`:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    Button boton;

    public MyViewHolder (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        boton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                         //Realiza algo!
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

---

En cuanto a el código de tu pregunta te sugiero usar el constructor de la clase para inicializar el listener:

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

public EscanerFragment() {

//Inicializa listener
onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator intent = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(EscanerFragment.this);
            intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
            intent.setCameraId(0);
            intent.setBeepEnabled(false);
            intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            intent.initiateScan();
        }
    }

}
```

posteriormente lo defines a tu botón

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escaner, container, false);

    etCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.etCodigo);
    btnLeerCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_escanear);

    //escanear();

    //Define listener.
    btnLeerCodigo.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);


    return vista;
}
```

Comment: Buenas @jorgesys, primero perdonad soy nuevo y aveces no doy la cantidad de detalles necesarios, el recyclerview lo tengo en otro fragment y los listener me funcionan bien, en cuanto a la otra parte (la del escaner) que es lo único que no me funciona, mañana a primera hora en cuanto pueda, os digo algo, muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buenas, acabo de probar a meterlo en el constructor y sigue sin funcionar, no da ningún error ni nada.

Comment: Primero trata de agregar  un mensaje dentro de click y dime si no se está llamando? me parece que tu problema es cuando se recibe el intent.

Comment: Ya lo tengo solucionado, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.